# Chroot live disk

Tags: chroot, livecd

How will you chroot into your Linux system using a live disc?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply mount the filesystem :

`mount /dev/sdXY /mnt`

Then :

`chroot /mnt`

Before you chroot, there are a few other things you may want to do.  For example, if you want to install programs, etc then you'll need to set up name resolution and such. Here's part of a "how to make a custom live dvd" howto that explains the actual commands - skip down to the end for how to clean up and exit the chroot and umount what is needed...

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LiveCDCustomization#Prepare_and_chroot